# Not start the queue by wisper-sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, wisper

I'm trying to make a small example with [wisper-sidekiq](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper-sidekiq) gem. The queue is created, but it does not start. Why? I will describe the steps that you are doing, I think it will be easier. I hope for your help.

A. controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
def create
    service = CreateBook.new
    service.subscribe(ActivityListener, async: true)
    service.on(:reserver_item_successfull) { |book| redirect_to book_path(book.id) }
    service.on(:reserver_item_failed)      { |book| @book = Book.new(book_params); respond_with(@book) }
    service.execute(current_user, book_params)
end
```

B. service:

```
require 'wisper/sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq/api'

class CreateBook
  include Wisper::Publisher

  def execute(performer, attributes)
    book = Book.new(attributes)
    if book.valid?
      book.save
      broadcast(:reserver_item_successfull, performer, book)
    else
      broadcast(:book_failed, performer, book)
    end
  end
end
```

C. listener:

```
class ActivityListener
  def self.reserver_item_successfull(performer, book)
    puts performer.name.to_s + ", book: " + book.title.to_s
  end
end
```

When I save the book, then of course creates a queue. But:

- sidekiq silent (the logs are empty, but the queue was created)
- redis silent too

Maybe I'm wrong start redis (*redis-server*) or sidekiq (*bundle exec sidekiq*)? Please help me.

P.S. Try *bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production sidekiq -q default -C config/sidekiq.yml*, but not result. The *sidekiq.rb* empty.

Comment: Next time you cross-post to both SO and the Issue Tracker can you include the link to each other so effort is not duplicated in answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I had to run sidekiq:

bundle exec sidekiq-r ./server.rb-L log/sidekiq.log
also in server.rb

require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
end

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get this fixed by the following steps:

- `require 'sidekiq/web'` and then, `mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'`
- go to `/sidekiq` to see if there're workers/tasks/queues
- if there aint

  - something may be wrong with your redis
  - or your code, put a `binding.pry` there
- if there're, must be something wrong with your code, put a `binding.pry` there

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Sidekiq says that the queue is have.